# Data is not saving in the sql lite core database

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I created project for core data, I wrote the code for it, But it is not saving the data in sql database.

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mobileTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var stateTextField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



@IBAction func saveButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    let dict = ["name":nameTextField.text,"email":emailTextField.text,"mobile":mobileTextField.text,"state":stateTextField.text]

    DatabaseHelper.shareInstance.save(object: dict as! [String : String])
}

//MARK: TextField Delagate mthods

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

}



//  DatabaseHelper.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DatabaseHelper{

static var shareInstance = DatabaseHelper() //it is required if you want to access following method outside any class

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext

func save(object:[String:String]){

    let student = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Student", into: context!) as! Student

    student.name = object["name"]
    student.email = object["email"]
    student.mobile = object["mobile"]
    student.state = object["state"]

    do{

        try context?.save()
    }catch{
      print("daata is not save")
    }

}

}



//AppDelegate.swift

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        print("Document Directory :",FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last ?? "Not Found")

        return true
    }
```

I did all necessary code in order to create core data project, but I am not able to save the data into the sql database.

Can anyone tell/help me, what I am missing in the code?

I am using Xcode 11.0 and 5

[The complete project you can find here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16beFCWUD8ocp8j6Q6tCgCzaov3QSxvH3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: At least print the `error` rather than a pretty meaningless literal string.

Comment: Which Xcode version you are using?

Comment: Your code is working fine. Just delete the currently installed app and try again. Probably the existing app uses old schema.

Comment: @Mithub MP sure I will try by doing deleted existing app

Comment: I am using Xcode 11 and swift 5.1

Comment: @MKiOS: Yes, I'm also using Xcode 11. I've checked the db file using an sqlite client and saw that the data is there. No error is thrown.

Comment: @Midhun MP how I can get url (file path) so I can check the saved data in sql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following code to print(get) your data.

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Student")

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
               print(data.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
          }

        } catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
```